# Подключить 25 web камер через USB в одному компьютеру

Tags: usb, драйвер, железо, web-camera

Есть задача подключить 25 web камер через USB(2.0) к одному компьютеру и работать с ними одновременно. Я нашел слот расширения PCI для добавления дополнительных 8 USB(3.0) портов. Теоретически можно было бы подлючить несколько таких слотов. Но проблема в том, что этот слот добавляет только одну дополнительную шину USB и ее пропускной способности не хватает для одновременной работы 8 камер, даже не смотря на то, что дополнительные порты имеют интерфейс USB 3.0. Я тестировал на Ubuntu 16.04 и на Windows 10. Как я могу решить данную задачу? Посоветуйте любые возможные решения. Может быть можно установить какой-нибудь другой драйвер, или изменить настройки системы. Или вообще может есть какая-нибудь дополнительная железка, которая позволит решить задачу. Разрешения с камер хотелось бы не меньше чем 720p, частота кадров 25 fps. Не знаю каких-либо специализированных "железных" решений, поэтому и задаю вопрос. В сторону каких-либо сторонних программ думаю смотреть бессмысленно, так как камеры просто не могут работать с нужной скоростью на одном PCI.

Comment: Вы смотрели в сторону специализированных решений, чем они не подходят? Какие требования к разрешению и частоте кадров? Внести уточнения в вопрос плиз, кнопка "править"

Comment: Надо еще посчитать, хватит ли производительности самой шины PCI для обслуживания 25 камер. Кстати, бывают веб-камеры с выходом сразу на гиговую Ethernet-шину. Но производительность все равно придется считать. В крайнем случает придется ставить несколько компов.

Comment: интересно какая цель преследуется? сэкономить на камерах? что Вы дальше делаете с этим видео?

Comment: Скорость PCI-E 2.0 насколько я знаю около 400 МБ/c этого должно хватить для 25 камер.

Comment: Сложно что то сказать, не знач формат данных, некоторые камеры аппаратно жмут в h264, например..

Comment: Когда-то давно я прикидывал и у меня получалось, что два гиговых Ethernet-канала полностью грузят PCI-шину (если работают на полной скорости). А тут надо еще смотреть какой поток выдают Ваши камеры. Есть камеры высокой четкости, а есть 600 на 400.

Comment: Поддержу @StrangerintheQ. Мне кажется, что тут - ошибка молотка. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191416